# plot masked data on plotly map

Tags: python, numpy, plotly

I have data (latitude, longitude and measurement data) coming from a netCDF file (including a fill value), in a masked numpy array.

When I plot these data with plolty on an interactive map, all values, also the masked ones get plotted. The masked values are then plotted with the fill value from the netCDF file.

Is there a way to plot these data *without* the masked data?

The code I have so far:

```
    fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=lat.flatten(),
        lon=lon.flatten(),
        mode='markers',
    text=aod.flatten(),
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size=5, color=data.flatten(), cmin=0, cmax=4
        )        
    ))



    fig.update_layout(
    autosize=True,
    hovermode='closest',
    mapbox=dict(
        style="open-street-map",
        bearing=0,
        pitch=0,))
    fig.show()
```